# How to Replacing process on a string that gets from Xml file

Tags: android, xml, replace

I get some string from xml as using XmlPullparser.

```
 String test ;
 if (name.equals("content")) 
    test = myParser.getAttributeValue(null, "value").toString();
```

Bythe way the xml side look like this

```
 <content value = "sometext">
```

These are some part of my code. The code upperside returns 'sometext'. So simple. But when i try to some operations on this string value there is nothing changed.I mean

```
Textview tv = ....
tv.setText(test);
```

It seems what it is , textview's text happens "sometext".
After this i try to change some characters.

```
   test.replace('e', 'a');
   tv.setText(test);
```

It has to seem after this "somataxt", but it still seem "sometext". There is something wrong here :)

Comment: please check my ans below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you just replace the 'e' with 'a' but never assign return value from [replace(char, char)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) to test String object:

```
test = test.replace('e', 'a');
tv.setText(test);
```

**OR**

```
tv.setText(test.replace('e', 'a'));
```

Comment: This works too, i didnt know the replace function returns as string. it doesnt change the string that is parameter

Comment: There is one more question i want to ask. Actualy the content value is    out.println('Firs line'); \n       out.println('Second line'); \n when i try to replace "\n" it doesn work. When i load the content value as manuel the \n values change.

Comment: can you please elaborate more ?

Comment: i mean you know test string, it's default value comes from xml side is "this is first line \n". i want to change "\n" values with System.getProperty("line.separator"). It doesnt work. But if i give the test value with my hand i mean if it doesnt come from xml the "\n" values changes with what i want.

Comment: can you please ask new question with this problem just provide me link here.

Comment: i cant ask befora 90 mins.